# How to clear all the markers in v2 google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to clear all markers in v2 google map. And again need to add some markers. If anybody knows the answer kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: See http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/hiding-and-showing-on-screen-markers-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 22):

You can either use [`googleMap.clear()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear%28%29), or you can store your Markers in a collection of some kind and remove them in a loop:

```
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers;
...
private void removeMarkers() {
    for (Marker marker: mMarkers) {
        marker.remove();
    }
    mMarkers.clear();
}
```

Comment: clear() will do the job. the second solution will remove from the arraylist and then you will have to update your view/refresh i guess

Comment: Don't forget to call `mMarkers.clear();` at the end of `removeMarkers` function.

Comment: Raghunandan: marker.remove() removes the marker from the map. MaciejGórski: good catch, updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

ex - if you want to refresh and load new marker point in the map for a button click(in this ex i get button click),

```
    switch ( view.getId() ) {
        case R.id.buttonOne:

    //clear googlemap
    googleMap.clear();
    //call to generate new marker
    this.getMarker(lat,lang);
        break;
        }

//to add new marker
public void getMarker ( String lat,String lang ) {

LatLng latLang = new LatLng( lat, lang);
//call to your googlemap implementation method
this.getGoogleMap();
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLang))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Map object and call clear to clear the markers.

```
mMap.clear();
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#clear()

Check the docs

`public final void clear ()`

Removes all `markers, polylines, polygons, overlays`, etc from the map.

Answer (score 1):

just create a method as  `clearOverlays()`

and inside the method

```
public void clearOverlays(){
        if(mMap!=null){
            mMap.clear();
        }else{
            Log.d("Maps::","mMap is null");
        }
    }
```

where mMap is

```
public static GoogleMap mMap;
```

That `mMap` will initialize automatically inside the
`public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` method .

There put `mMap = googleMap;`

Now use the `clearOverlays()` method wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16871246/2003486) would be helpful for you. Take all the markers in a List and refresh the map view whenever you need to replace markers by clearing the object of Google Map and List variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use clear() in java and kotlin

**java**

```
 googleMap.clear()
```

**kotlin**

```
 googleMap?.clear()
```