# when I add a set of markers from array list it show only the last value from array list?

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Adding markers in Google map using the array list values but it fetches only the  Last value from array list please help.Here is my loop given below.

```
                for(int k=0;k<jsonarray2.length();k++)
                    {
                        jsonobject2 =jsonarray2.getJSONObject(k);
                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map1.put("Lat",jsonobject2.getString("Lat"));

                        Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject2.getString("Lat"));
                        map1.put("Long",jsonobject2.getString("Long"));
                        map1.put("StopName", jsonobject2.getString("StopName"));
                        Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject2.getString("Long"));
                        //      map1.put("LiveLongitude",jsonobject1.getString("LiveLongitude"));

                        //       Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject1.getString("LiveLongitude"));


                        arraylist12.add(map1);

                        Log.e("arraylist12", ""+arraylist12);

                         for (int m = 0; m < arraylist12.size(); m++) { 

                            final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double .parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Lat")),Double.parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Long"))); 
                            Log.e("position", ""+position);                             
                            String stopname = arraylist12.get(m).get("StopName");
                            if(mark!=null){
                                mark.remove();
                            }
                            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(position); 

                            //mMap.addMarker(options); 
                            mark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.bustour)).title(stopname));
```

}

Comment: @RanjitPati yes because  am adding marker when i click a marker which is stable  in google map ,So if i click a marker in google map it has to show the set of related markers from array list,but after that if i click any other stable markers  the markers which added before should be removed and the new set of related markers to be added.Please help

Comment: you are explicitly removing the marker by  `if(mark!=null){
                            mark.remove();
                        }`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar How can I resolve it please help me ?

Comment: remove that part of code.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar If i remove it how can I remove the markers and add the new one ???

Comment: please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar In my application am using google map when the application launches the set of markers will be displayed ,please Assume the set of markers as A ,when i click any one of the marker in "A" another set of markers will be generated and added Assume it as "B",So after that if I again click any markers in"A" the previous "B marker" should be removed and the new set of "B" Marker should be added.So only i use the mark.remove but it showing only the last value from "B"

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Can you explain me in detail please ?I have added the code in On click of "A"only

Comment: Kindly move this `if(mark!=null){
                            mark.remove();
                        }` before the loop.

Comment: Check code here http://paste.ofcode.org/LMmXACfXdMPKfbtiLASMUA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91707/discussion-between-ganesan-g-and-muhammad-babar).

Answer (score 1):

I think this much code is fine to add multiple markers through loop..

```
for (int m = 0; m < arraylist12.size(); m++) { 
    final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double .parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Lat")),Double.parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Long"))); 

    String stopname = arraylist12.get(m).get("StopName");
    mark=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.bustour)).title(stopname));
}
```

If you will use `if(mark!=null){mark.remove();}` , then it will remove the last marker before adding the new one..so at last you can only see the last marker..

**EDIT**

You you want to remove the set of markers before adding a new set, then just clear the map before adding new marker set.

something like:: `mMap.clear();`  then add the new set..

Comment: without adding the line how can I remove the previous set of markers before adding the new one?

Comment: I think you want to show all markers in one map.Right ..then why you want to remove the last one.

Comment: @ganesang you need to add previous set of marker is a Hashmap<String,Marker> and then you could iterate to remove all of them!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I added it in Hashmap only kindly check the above code I updated

Comment: @ganesang store variable `mark` to the hashmap when you are adding them on map for the very first time next time on click on A you need to remove all the mark that are already stored in hashmap at once and then try adding the new markers!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar can you please edit the above code ??

Comment: @RanjitPati if I clear the map the map will be reloaded but I need to only remove the markers and add the new sets

Comment: then remove each marker one by one just before the loop..make sure the marker list is not null before removing anything from it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197325/how-to-clear-all-the-markers-in-v2-google-map