# Android - how to count markers in GoogleMap APIv2

Tags: android, count, maps

I want when I set more than two markers they to disappear.

I wrote this code but it seems is not working.

Thanks  in advance.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            map.addMarker(markerOptions);

 List<MarkerOptions> aList = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
            aList.add(markerOptions);

            int p;

            for(p = 0; p<aList.size(); p++){

            }

            if(p>2){

                map.clear();
            }
```

Comment: check this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853182/android-how-to-remove-all-markers-from-google-map-v2

Answer (score 0):

Whats your error message?

Your code isn't very clear. Where is markerOptions coming from? Is it meant to be more than one? You might need a loop to add them, or use .addAll.

Your for loop is pretty redundant too.

Try something more like this:

```
List<MarkerOptions> aList = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();

aList.addAll(markerOptions);

if(aList.size()>2)
{
    map.clear();
}
```